# Shared folder inaccessible after unplugging then plugging back Ethernet cable

Tags: windows, networking, ics

I have this set-up between two laptops that was suiting my needs until today, because laptop B (a budget Schneider lappy with a 32GB SSD) can't accomodate much in the way of big files, namely videos and songs, and laptop A (a 2011 Lenovo ThinkPad) now has a 500GB SSD with plenty of space, plus I can plug an external HDD that can host the same amount of data (500GB).

I also set ICS to share my Internet connection between WiFi on laptop A and Ethernet on laptop B (I have to use an Ethernet-to-USB adapter, because laptop B only has two USB ports, no Ethernet).

I try to avoid sharing files over WiFi because our router has a high latency, and Internet is shared with my roommates, so I don't want them to sniff my files.

Up until now, I could open, say, a video stored on laptop A with VLC on laptop B via Ethernet. Video/music play worked like a charm and all was well.

Just an hour ago, I unplugged the Ethernet cable on laptop A to make room on my desk. I lost connectivity to the shared folder, as was normal.

Problem is, when I plugged the Ethernet cable back again, I couldn't, and still can't despite all my efforts, access the shared folder on laptop A again...

To add insult to injury, I can access the Web through this cable connection, but I can't access the shared folder. In other words, without any other network adapter enabled on laptop B (no WiFi, since there's nothing else) than the Ethernet-to-USB, I can browse the Web to my heart's content, but I can open a video in the shared folder on laptop A.

I tried disabling then re-enabling ICS, no go, still no access to the shared folder and, of course, no access to the Web on laptop B either when disabled.

Tried rebooting both laptops, to no avail.

Tried network troubleshooting on laptop B (laptop A is fine when it comes to networking): zippo. I only get a "No valid IP configuration - Not corrected" message, and that's it.

Tried un-sharing, then re-sharing the folder in question, no go.

A bridge connection is not an option, since Microsoft broke the darn thing with a recent upgrade. Only in Windows Server will it work, not in Windows 10, not anymore, no sir.

Tried to disable then re-enable the network adapter on laptop B: zilch.

How can I make this folder permanently shared between the two PCs, given that I unplug the cable very often, due to the fact that I do other stuff on this desk, other than using the laptops?

EDIT: the cable is fine, it's brand-new, and like I said, the set-up was working fine just over an hour ago.

Comment: Try the following on both computers:  

Reset TCP/IP as follows: 

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(2) Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(3) Then: ipconfig /flushdns
(4) Then: restart the computer and test the sharing. Make sure both computers are on Private and not Public network connections

Comment: I got it to work again, by disabling folder sharing completely, rebooting laptop A, enabling folder sharing again, and making sure the networking mapping service on laptop B was running (it's set to auto, but won't start and remain on; I have to manually restart it), so that network discovery was working again on laptop B. I haven't tried to unplug the cable yet, will do that later and see if connection is lost again. I'll try your commands if and when I cross that bridge, and not a second sooner...! :-) Thanks for the advice, I'm keeping it in a corner of my head.

Comment: Addendum: I usually put both laptops in hibernation at night. Could it have an effect of any kind on network discovery, like unloading drivers from RAM or something?

Comment: I disconnect folder sharing before suspending or hibernating and reconnect after waking up.  Please let me know if this and my first answer here and I will formulate an answer for you

Comment: Will do. Thanks for taking the time. I'll keep you posted tomorrow (it's 11:15 pm here, I'm going to be)!